# VS 2017 cross-project linking error inside one solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, googletest

I'm trying to develop some C++ skills by doing a light open-source project using Visual Studio 2019.

The solution includes two projects: one for the application (luacalls), one for the tests (luacalls-tests). Instead of declaring everything as `__cdecl`/`DLLEXPORT` like some answers here recommend, I decided simply to include all source files from the application project into the test project as well (as the application is expected to be quite small in terms of LoC). Here's what it looks like in Solution Explorer (pardon the Russian):

[image: Solution Explorer]

Here's `main.cpp` from luacalls-tests:

```
#include <sstream>

#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "../luacalls/run.h"
#include "../luacalls/lexer.h"

TEST(Run, RunThrowsOnInvalidFilename) {
    char* argv[]{ "_", "Z:\\nonexistent.file" };
    ASSERT_THROW(run(2, argv), std::runtime_error);
}

TEST(LexerTests, LexerParsesIntegers) {
    std::stringstream ss{ "9519292" };
    Lexer lexer{ std::move(ss) };
    auto lexer_iter = lexer.begin();
    EXPECT_EQ(std::get<double>(*lexer_iter), 9519292);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

The `run` function is called without issue and passes the corresponding test. The other test, however, fails to compile with 3 linking errors LNK2019 ("Unresolved external symbol"). `run` and `Lexer` both have their declaration and definition split into `.h` and `.cpp` files respectively. Here's `lexer.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include <variant>

enum class Keyword {
    // something...
};

enum class Operator {
    // something else...
};

enum class SyntaxToken {
    // something else again...
};

using Identifier = std::string;
using StringLiteral = std::string;
using Token = std::variant<Keyword, Identifier, StringLiteral, long long, double, Operator, SyntaxToken>;

template <typename InputStream>
struct Lexer {
    struct LexerIteratorEnd {
        bool operator!=(LexerIteratorEnd);
    };

    struct LexerIterator {
        friend Lexer;
        LexerIterator(LexerIterator&);
        Token& operator*();
        LexerIterator& operator++();
        LexerIterator operator++(int);
        bool operator!=(LexerIteratorEnd) const;
    private:
        LexerIterator(Lexer<InputStream>);
        Lexer<InputStream>& lexer_;
    };

    Lexer(InputStream&&);
    LexerIterator begin();
    LexerIteratorEnd end();
    bool empty();
private:
    void advance();
    InputStream is_;
    Token current_lexeme_{};
};
```

And `lexer.cpp` as well:

```
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>

#include "lexer.h"

template <typename InputStream>
bool Lexer<InputStream>::LexerIteratorEnd::operator!=(LexerIteratorEnd ignored) {
    return false;
}

// LexerIterator

template <typename InputStream>
Lexer<InputStream>::LexerIterator::LexerIterator(LexerIterator& other) : lexer_{ other.lexer_ } {}

template <typename InputStream>
typename Lexer<InputStream>::LexerIterator& Lexer<InputStream>::LexerIterator::operator++() { // prefix increment
    lexer_.next();
}

template <typename InputStream>
typename Lexer<InputStream>::LexerIterator Lexer<InputStream>::LexerIterator::operator++(int) { // postfix increment
    LexerIterator tmp{ *this };
    operator++();
    return tmp;
}

template <typename InputStream>
bool Lexer<InputStream>::LexerIterator::operator!=(LexerIteratorEnd ignored) const {
    LexerIterator tmp{ *this };
    operator++();
    return tmp;
}

template <typename InputStream>
Token& Lexer<InputStream>::LexerIterator::operator*() {
    return lexer_.current_lexeme_;
}

template <typename InputStream>
Lexer<InputStream>::LexerIterator::LexerIterator(Lexer<InputStream> lexer) : lexer_{ lexer } {}

// Lexer

template <typename InputStream>
Lexer<InputStream>::Lexer(InputStream&& is) : is_{ std::move(is) } {}

template <typename InputStream>
typename Lexer<InputStream>::LexerIterator Lexer<InputStream>::begin() {
    return LexerIterator{ *this };
}

template <typename InputStream>
typename Lexer<InputStream>::LexerIteratorEnd Lexer<InputStream>::end() {
    return LexerIterator{ *this };
}

template <typename InputStream>
bool Lexer<InputStream>::empty() {
    return is_.eof();
}

template <typename InputStream>
void Lexer<InputStream>::advance() {
    current_lexeme_ = 25.0;
}
```

Quick Internet search reveals that "Unresolved external symbol" error occurs when there's a declaration without the corresponding definition. However, I'm pretty sure I've defined every method for the class (and Visual Studio helpfully highlights declarations for which it can't find definitions). Any pointers would be appreciated. Maybe I should man up and switch to some "canonical" way of coupling testing facilities with the application?

Comment: I think your bug is you implemented your template in a .cpp file.

Comment: Wow. How is one even supposed to know about that? BTW, the code above has a billion errors, as it turns out. Don't use it, please ;) And thank you for the answer, of course!